# LinkedList Recursive Appending

Tags: java

I need to recursively append a Node to a linked list, not sure why my code doesn't work

```
public void RecursiveAppend(Node example, Node add){
   if(example == null){
       example = add; 
   } else {
       RecursiveAppend(example.next, add);
   }
}
```

Method to print list

```
public void IterativeTraversal(){
       Node example = m_head;
       while(example != null){
           System.out.print(example.data + " ");
           example = example.next;
       }
   }
public class LinkedListDemo {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        LinkedList example = new LinkedList();
        Node A = new Node(10);
        Node B = new Node(30);
        Node C = new Node(50);
        Node D = new Node(70);
        example.append(A);
        example.append(B);
        example.append(C);
        example.RecursiveAppend(D);
        example.IterativeTraversal();
    }
}
```

Result: 10 30 50

Answer (score 0):

You would want to check to see if `example.next == null` then set example.next to add instead of checking for `example == null` because if you need to be able to assign example.next and you can not do that if you have moved passed the node.

Answer (score 0):

So `null + 1 = null`  `null * 1 = null` similary you have set `example` to `null` in here

```
if(example == null){
  example = add; 
}
```

your base condition will be executed when there's a `null` value.
so say you present node data is `40` and its next is `null`, So after 40 `RecursiveAppend(example.next, add);` this will make example as `null` and so Your base case hits `if(example == null)` and in there its `example = add;` which means `null = add` Which is null.
To over come this your base case should hit when the `current node` next has `null` like.

```
 if(example.next == null){
       example.next = add; 
   }
```

And this will solve the problem. Overall code

```
public void RecursiveAppend(Node example, Node add){
   if(example.next == null){
       example.next = add; 
   } else {
       RecursiveAppend(example.next, add);
   }
```